# split string only on first occurence of specified character

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to split a string at the first occurence of "/" character. I'm able to split it into multiple elements using split('/') but when I try to split the the string at the 1st occurence of "/" character using a greedy operator (?) I'm not able to get the desired string..

Javascript Code

```
var url_string ="http://localhost:8080/myapp.html#/"
var sub_url = url_string.split(/(.+)?/)[1];
```

Current output.

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp.html#/
```

Desired Output..

```
myapp.html#/
```

Can't understand what I'm doing wrong.please help!!

Comment: Why don't you replace "http://localhost:8080/" with empty and declare a variable with that value; ie: var SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:8080/"; var sub_url = url_string.replace(SERVER_URL, "")

Comment: Or `.split(/\/(?=[^\/]*\/$)/)[1]`

Comment: Or [`/[^\/]*\/$/`](https://regex101.com/r/Ls40Yx/1)

Comment: You can directly use AngularJS service [$location.url()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location): `var sub_url = $location.url();`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero is this angular?

Comment: Yes, go to the provided link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the power of [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and adjust the result.

```js
var url_string = "http://localhost:8080/myapp.html#/"
var url = document.createElement('a');

url.href = url_string;
console.log(url.pathname.slice(1) + url.hash);
```

Comment: The OP ask for: `myapp.html#/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use AngularJS `$location.url()` from the service [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location):

```
// given URL http://localhost:8080/myapp.html#/
var url = $location.url();
// => "/myapp.html#/"
```

... and remove the first character.

Or you can the Web API [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL):

```js
var url = new URL('http://localhost:8080/myapp.html#/');
console.log(url.pathname.slice(1) + url.hash);
```